# Method initializing an object in a dispatch_sync Block flagged by static analyzer as returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, objective-c-blocks

I am unable to figure out why Xcode's static analyzer is giving me the warning "'nil' returned from a method that is expected to return a non-null value". The method is:

```
- (NSURLSessionUploadTask *)uploadTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                     fromFile:(NSURL *)fileURL
                                     progress:(NSProgress * __autoreleasing *)progress 
                                     completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error))completionHandler {
__block NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = nil;
dispatch_sync(url_session_manager_creation_queue(), ^{
    uploadTask = [self.session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:fileURL];
});

if (!uploadTask && self.attemptsToRecreateUploadTasksForBackgroundSessions && self.session.configuration.identifier) {
    for (NSUInteger attempts = 0; !uploadTask && attempts < AFMaximumNumberOfAttemptsToRecreateBackgroundSessionUploadTask; attempts++) {
        uploadTask = [self.session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:fileURL];
    }
}

[self addDelegateForUploadTask:uploadTask progress:progress completionHandler:completionHandler];

return uploadTask; // nil returned from a method that is expected to return a non-null value
}
```

Comment: Analyzer states : nil returned from a method that is expected to return a non-null value

Comment: How is this method declared in the `.h` file? And does it override a superclass method?

Comment: Is `self.session` nullable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The analyzer takes cues from your own code. The fact that your code is checking if `uploadTask` is `nil` tells the analyzer (regardless of anything else it might know about the methods you're calling), that it might be `nil`. There's a chance that it would keep being `nil` even after `attempts` exceeds `AFMaximumNumberOfAttemptsToRecreateBackgroundSessionUploadTask`. Your own code tells it that. And, if so, and assuming that your method is declared to return a non-`nil` pointer, then you'd be violating your design contract.